# Override Backbone.sync() at Model level to send extra params?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

To be quite honest I'm stuck trying to override Backbone's sync() method for a Model, I have the signature for the function in place, and it gets triggered correctly, but **I don't know what to put in the function body** in order for it to make a default call to DELETE but **with extra arguments**.
ie.

```
class Master.Models.Member extends Backbone.Model
  urlRoot: '/api/members/'

  sync: (method, model, options) ->
    params = _.clone options
    Backbone.sync method, model, params
```

I call it like this:

```
......
remove: ->
  @model.destroy
    collective_id: the_id
```

My intention there, is to pass the **collective_id** param you see there to the server. But even though it's inside the options hash for sync() and I clone it, *It won't make it to the server!*
**How can I send that extra param to the server?**

(As it is, the only thing that reaches the server is the Model's id)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your model can contain it's own `Sync` method try it out, it receives same parameters as that of `Backbone.Sync`

Comment: have you solved the problem?

Comment: I had to go to the doctor this morning, I will try the answers now. Will report soon enough, Thank you VERY MUCH! I certainly appreciate your kindness.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

When you call .destroy(), .fetch() or .save() they all call Model.sync which only calls Backbone.sync. It's a proxy function. This is intended to provide a nice hook for modifying the AJAX behavior of a single model or any models that extend from that model.

- **Solution 1**: Override the Global Backbone.sync to `JSON.stringify` and modify the `contentType` when you've specified data to be sent with the delete request.

  - Pros: You can call `model.destroy()` and optionally pass in an `options` parameter
- **Solution 2** - Override the Model.sync method.

  - Pros: The override only affects individual models. Isolated changes.
  - Cons: All models that wish to delete with data need to extend from the correct 'base model'
- **Solution 3** - Don't override anything and explicitly call model.sync with all of the `stringify` and `contentType` stuff.

  - Pros: Very isolated changes, won't affect any other models. Useful if you're integrating with a large codebase.

#### [[Solution 1] - Global Override of Backbone.sync (this will affect all models)](http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/hMuQt/)

**javacript version**

```
var oldBackboneSync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.sync = function( method, model, options ) {
    // delete request WITH data
    if ( method === 'delete' && options.data ) {
        options.data = JSON.stringify(options.data);
        options.contentType = 'application/json';
    } // else, business as usual.
    return oldBackboneSync.apply(this, [method, model, options]);
}
```

**Usage**:

```
var model, SomeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ /* urlRoot, initialize, etc... */});
model = new SomeModel();
model.destroy({
    data: {
        /* data payload to send with delete request */
    }
});
```

---

#### [[Solution 2] - Override Backbone.destroy on a base model and extend other models from that.](http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/VVJhg/)

**override**

```
// Create your own 'enhanced' model 
Backbone.EnhancedModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    destroy: function( options ) {
        if ( options.data ) {
            // properly formats data for back-end to parse
            options.data = JSON.stringify(options.data);
        }
        // transform all delete requests to application/json
        options.contentType = 'application/json';
        Backbone.Model.prototype.destroy.call(this, options);
    }
});
```

**usage**

```
var model, SomeModel = Backbone.EnhancedModel.extend({ /* urlRoot, initialize, etc... */})
model = new SomeModel();
SomeModel.destroy({
    data: {
        /* additional data payload */
    }
});
```

---

#### [[Solution 3] - Call .destroy() with correct parameters.](http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/S3dd2/)

If sending data with your destroy requests is an isolated thing, then this is an adequate solution.

When calling `model.destroy()` pass in the `data` and `contentType` options like so:

**javascript version/usage**

```
var additionalData = { collective_id: 14 };
model.destroy({
    data: JSON.stringify(additionalData),
    contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

---

### The "Problem" (with Backbone, not solutions):

Backbone.js makes the assumption ([view source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-135)) that delete requests **do not** have a data payload.

```
// delete methods are excluded from having their data processed and contentType altered.
if (options.data == null && model && (method === 'create' || method === 'update' || method === 'patch')) {
      params.contentType = 'application/json';
      params.data = JSON.stringify(options.attrs || model.toJSON(options));
}
```

In their assumed RESTful API call, the only data required is the ID which should be appended to a `urlRoot` property.

```
var BookModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'api/book'
});
var book1 = new BookModel({ id: 1 });
book1.destroy()
```

The delete request would be sent like

```
DELETE => api/book/1
contentType: Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Yes, as I've mentioned on a comment for the other answer, this didn't work for me. I'm using version #2 of your solution.

Comment: Perhaps there's something I'm missing in the way I'm overriding sync() for my model? Thanks again, sir.

Comment: inside of that options/params object, you need to include all of the additional data in the `data` attribute but you have to stringify it first. that data attribute will get sent along with the $.ajax request. You'll also need to change the contentType to application/json so the server can parse it

Comment: I think, I've done that, that's pretty much what's detailed in the answers, right? However, I don't understand what you mean by $.ajax request? is that what this part: Backbone.sync(method, model, options) do behind the scenes? Thank you for your reply, sir.

Comment: Yep. http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-144 The top 3 lines of code are the last 3 lines in Backbone.sync. The `options` that you pass into Backbone.Sync get mixed into this params object that the Backbone code creates as part of Backbone.sync and then are sent along with the AJAX request. `options.data` is sent with the AJAX request but you need to call JSON.stringify on it first and specify the correct contentType so that the back-end can parse it correctly

Comment: Even If override at Model level? is that ok?

Comment: You should override sync at the model level instead of globally. Just make sure that you call `Backbone.sync.apply(this, arguments)` at the end of your override

Comment: Hopefully, you won't interpret this as me being lazy, but perhaps you could paste the code sample based on my original code post for the Model override of sync(), this is very confusing to me, it's the first time I'm using backbone.js, it seems you grasp the concepts very well, Thank you for your replies :)

Comment: I just did :d You should drop a debugger in your code and follow along with Backbone. It pays to learn about the library.. it is a bit confusing at first but it's not as complex as it seems.

Comment: I'll set up a JSFiddle with the solutions

Comment: thanks, this is still very confusing to me, I'm sorry, for instance, I'm still puzzled as to where do I put the code that overrides sync globally. The docs aren't very clear about that.. so, If you place a fiddle I couldn't be any happier :)

Comment: solution 1: http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/hMuQt/ ---- solution 2: http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/VVJhg/ --- solution 3: http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/S3dd2/

Comment: I updated solution 2 to override the `destroy` method instead of the `sync` method. It makes more sense.

Comment: Alright, Here's the thing, I've noticed by looking in Chrome's console that the parameter is indeed being sent to the server (as Request Payload), I'm programming in Ruby on Rails, so what I see as parameters sent to the server is contained in the params Hash, ie. ( {"action"=>"destroy", "controller"=>"membership", "id"=>"3"} ), as you can see, still no extra parameter (collective_id), How can I get that param (Request payload) out on the server side? Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not completely sure about the RoR side. Can you look in the Request Body instaed of the Params Hash? Or is the Params Hash all you have to look at? Sending data with a DELETE request is pretty non-standard so maybe RoR ignores it or something?

Comment: Better solution might be to do a PUT or POST to a api/object/delete or api/object/{id}/delete URL with a body. Then modify your backbone code to work with that.

Comment: Yeah! I have thought about that too... but I have that actions for that Controller taken. I'm not sure how to change the PUT for backbone's REST API for just one action to go to another path.. :(

Comment: Thanks for all the Help, I've finally solved it! You were right, I had to take data out from the request object, then I just had to do some basic parsing :) Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Phew. I'd just about given up there :p

Comment: Just to note that you've mis-spelt 'application/json' in solution #1 and #2 - you've missed out the 'i'.  Caught me out with a copy/paste and I get a .Net server error: Unsupported Media Type

Comment: `When you call .destroy(), .fetch() or .save() they all eventually call Backbone.sync. They don't call Model.sync. Model.sync is ONLY called if you explicitly call it.`

I disagree. The [annotated source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-61) as of 2014-06-23 seems to imply that `Model.save` calls `this.sync`, which is by default a proxy to `Backbone.sync`, but can be overridden for every `Model` instance.

Comment: Thanks, I updated it. Model save, destroy & fetch all call this.sync. (the opposite of what i originally wrote :p) Back when I wrote this, I assumed that they didn't call model.sync because model.sync doesn't do anything.

Comment: Hello! How would you access the data passes to the destroy function un solution 3 in a nodeJS handler? Is it in request.body?

Comment: @Jeremy.S I believe so

Comment: @CoryDanielson: the solution 3 worked, but it was in the request.payload :) Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Params need to be sent in `options.data`, so try:

coffeescript

```
remove: () ->
  @model.destroy 
    data: JSON.stringify
      collective_id: the_id, 
    contentType: 'application/json'
```

javascript

```
remove: function() {
  return this.model.destroy({
    data: JSON.stringify({
      collective_id: the_id
    }),
    contentType: 'application/json'
  });
}
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick. I'm testing it now. The only issue i see is that if I do not call JSON.stringify() on the `data`, it doesn't get sent correctly. It will appear as [Object object] inside of the request  that i can view through chrome's network panel

Comment: Strange. What version of BB are you using? It should work just passing in the object. Have you overridden `sync` in any other ways? If so, remove your `sync` override and use the Backbone-native sync.

Comment: I'm trying it on JSFiddle. results: http://i.imgur.com/jzthVqv.png fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/YkYA6/

Comment: Looking at the annotated source, a DELETE request is the only type to not have it's data processed by JSON Stringify. Go to http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html and then CTRL + F for the text  "Ensure that we have the appropriate request data." Look to the right and you'll see a chunk of code that processes options.data for create, update and patch ONLY.

Comment: Yeah: http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-139 . Learn something new every day! For DELETE you have to `JSON.stringify` yourself.

Comment: Oohhh, and I just learned that you can get a link to the doc section by clicking that Paragraph icon...hahaa. I would edit your answer, but I'm not 100% sure of the coffeescript syntax. Data needs to be passed into JSON.stringify and the `contentType` probably needs to be set to `application/json`.

Comment: I edited your answer, I think it's solid now. It now sends as a `Request Payload` instead of `Form Data` http://i.imgur.com/KkP7phj.png

Comment: Thanks for the answers/comments guys, you're amazing. I just got back to the question now. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work for me. If I console.log the options object, I see the JSON Object with my additional parameter there, but it still won't reach the server :( What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: The coffeescript code was off. I'm not super familiar with it. It's fixed now